# Vectorizing thetas, rs combinations with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am generating thetas, radius ranges, cos_thetas and sin_thetas using numpy.

I am still left with code that is highly inefficient, in terms of getting those combinations.

I have tried to go down the path of vectorization but reshaping makes things worse.

I currently have the following code:

```
candidates = []
    
delta_r = 1
r_min = 50
r_max = 100
    
num_thetas = 6

# R and Theta ranges
dtheta = int(360 / num_thetas)

## Thetas is bins created from 0 to 360 degree with increment of the dtheta
thetas = np.arange(0, 360, step=dtheta)

## Radius ranges from r_min to r_max 
rs = np.arange(r_min, r_max, step=delta_r)

cos_thetas = np.cos(np.deg2rad(thetas))
sin_thetas = np.sin(np.deg2rad(thetas))     
for r in rs:
    for t in range(num_thetas):
        candidates.append((r, int(r * cos_thetas[t]), int(r * sin_thetas[t])))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) is your friend:

```
d = np.zeros((num_thetas*rs.size, 3), order = "F", dtype = int)
d[:,0] = np.repeat(rs, num_thetas)
d[:,1] = np.ravel(rs[:,None] * cos_thetas[:num_thetas]).astype(int)
d[:,2] = np.ravel(rs[:,None] * sin_thetas[:num_thetas]).astype(int)
```

Although far from perfect, this quick fix should give at least about one order of magnitude of improvement.

Comment: Thanks, this works with the code above but if you change the num_thetas to 100 (and the array dimensions to rs.shape[0]*num_thetas) it complains: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6000,) into shape (5000,)". Do you know what would the issue be?

Comment: Update: cos_thetas and sin_thetas need to be sliced for first num_thetas elements in order to replicate the logic from the code I posted.

Comment: @mangotango Yes, indeed, the error is raised if `num_thetas` is not equal to `thetas.size`, which happens when it is not a divider of 360. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about smth like this:
The example includes less values of the variables but you can adjust that.
The output is an array, but you can easily cast it into a list.

```
import numpy as np
rs = np.linspace(50, 100, 3)
theta = np.linspace(0, 360, 3)
rs_grid, theta = np.meshgrid(rs, theta)
mgrid = np.stack(
    [rs_grid,
     rs_grid*np.cos(theta),
     rs_grid*np.sin(theta)])
mgrid.T.reshape(-1, 3)
```

the output:

```
array([[ 50.        ,  50.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 50.        , -29.92300345, -40.05763179],
       [ 50.        , -14.18455457,  47.94578617],
       [ 75.        ,  75.        ,   0.        ],
       [ 75.        , -44.88450518, -60.08644768],
       [ 75.        , -21.27683186,  71.91867926],
       [100.        , 100.        ,   0.        ],
       [100.        , -59.84600691, -80.11526357],
       [100.        , -28.36910915,  95.89157234]])
```